# How to loop over a list with lapply and dplyr::filter function?

Tags: r, loops, filter

I have two data frame x and y, each contain information of 22 chromosomes, and I'd like to extract the intersection of the uniqID from each chromosome.
I've tried the following but get an error:

```
chromosome <- 1:22
list1 <- lapply(chromosome, function(x) x %>% filter(chr == chromosome) %>% select(uniqID))
list2 <- lapply(chromosome, function(y) y %>% filter(chr == chromosome) %>% select(uniqID))
list3 <- intersect(list1, list2)


Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Could anyone point out what could be the reason? Maybe I misused the lapply function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
list3 <- lapply(chromosome, function(p) 
                intersect(x$uniqID[x$chr == p], y$uniqID[y$chr == p]))
```

Here we find the common `uniqID` which are present in both `x` and `y` for each value of `chromosome`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it seems not quite what I expect to get. I was hoping to get a list of IDs listed according to different chromosomes, something like: 
[(chr1:) id1, id2, id3,..., 
(chr2:) id1, id2, id3,...,
 (chr22:) id1, id2, id3,...]

Comment: @Helena It is easier to help if you provide an example of your data. Can you check if the updated answer is what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you for making the code so concise! This is pretty much what I want. I misplaced the `function(x)` inside the lapply statement, which should be `function(chromosome)`.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(chromosome, ~  x %>%
                    filter(chr == .x) %>%
                    pull(uniqID)  %>%
                    intersect(y %>%
                              filter(chr == .x) %>%
                              pull(uniqID)))
```